# Are there functions with a constant output regardless of input, or functions whose input is limited to a single number? (Cartesian coordinates)

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry

I was wondering whether a function $y=f(x)$ can be defined such that (1) its value $y$ is always constant, no matter what number substitutes $x$, (2) its argument $x$ is limited to a single number? Examples of such function definitions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For #2, $f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2}$, or $f(x) = \sin^{-1} (1+|-x\cos x|). There are many functions with limited domains, one just has to mess with the function a bit.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley: That is an antediluvian notion of function. (And your second example is 'defined' for all $x=(2n+1)\pi$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are any sets, then a function from $X$ to $Y$ is simply an assignment of an element of $Y$ to each element of $X$. (More formally, it is a subset of the product set $X\times Y$ that satisfies certain conditions.)

So...

For (1), we can define for example a function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=99$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

For (2), we can only define such a function if $X$ consists of a single element. Not very useful!

Comment: @bp2017: that is an obsolete notion of what a function is, and not very useful. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A function is two sets with a mapping between them. Its domain could indeed consist of a single element, much like how its output could also be a single number. Think of the identity function $f:\{1\} \to \{1\}$ where $f(1)=1$. It clearly satisfies both of the properties you give.